# Formatting a UITableViewCell (or any text, for that matter)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How can I format a UITableViewCell in my UITableView to have text such as the following:

|Hello======More Text|

where the "|" symbols indicate the beginning and end of the UITableViewCell and the "=" symbold indicate spacing.

So I'm trying to have text A be left justified while at the same time, text B is right justified.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use standard cell with `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` style (same cells are used in standard Settings application). Set your "left text" to the cell's `textLabel`, and "right text" to the `detailTextLabel`, something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Left text";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Right text";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: actually it's saying "detailsTextLabel" isn't anything. is this a typo?